# Why does mfg resets automatically in R

Tags: r, par

In the following R code, when I set `par(omi = c(1,0,0,0))` the mfg parameter resets and the second plot is plotted at the `(1,1)` position. How can I avoid resetting mfg?

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
hist(rnorm(100))
par(omi = c(1,0,0,0))
boxplot(rnorm(100))
```

Comment: Do you want `par(omi = c(1,0,0,0), new=TRUE)`? It's not clear to me what the ultimate goal is.

Comment: My aim is to add to the margins between the plots (in this case bottom). Setting new = TRUE does not help. For example, try par(mfrow = c(1,3)) and try three plot and  somewhere in between add the command par(omi=c(1,0,0,0), new = TRUE). somehow par()$mfg seem to reset incorrectly.